# Windows 10 Messages notifies you with naughty stuff while streaming

Tags: windows-10

My friend has a problem with the windows messages on the right. He will randomly get notifications about winning free stuff and naughty stuff. It's a big problem because he's streaming, and when it pops up on screen... Yeah... So how do you remove the ads or the notifications at least?

He is using streamlabs obs and the tab in question is the live tab.

Comment: What program is "your friend" using for streaming?

Comment: streamlabs obs.

Comment: Ah so people are spamming in the comment window?

Comment: Remove the malware causing the ads. It’s not windows.

Comment: You should ask at https://support.streamlabs.com/hc/en-us

Comment: @Appleoddity I think he is referring to the streamlabs live tab.